# WPF Binding a Label's Visibility to a ScrollViewer's ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility

Tags: wpf, binding, scrollviewer

I have a ScrollViewer, it scrolls vertically only, and shows the vertical scroll bar if it needs to only:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

I also have a Label, which I only want to show if the ScrollViewer's vertical scroll bar is showing:

```
<Label Background="DarkBlue" Height="60" Width="70">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility.Visibility, ElementName=sv}" Value="Hidden">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

This does not seem to work.  I have searched for a solution, which normally I find quite quickly hence this being my first post.  Any suggestions on how to get this working?  I would prefer a xaml only solution but could be convinced to use converters and what-not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First **`ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility`** property is of type **`Visibility`**.
 So, you have to bind with ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility property only and not with ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility.Visibility.

Second, **`Value`** will be **`Collapsed`** and not **`Hidden`**

---

Update trigger to this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility,
                               ElementName=sv}" Value="Collapsed">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: This worked completely.  Thanks very much for this.  I hope others find this useful too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to bind your label's visibility directly to the scrollbar's computed visibility:

```
<Label Background="DarkBlue" Height="60" Width="70"
       Visibility="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=sv}" />
```

This way the label is only visible when the scrollbar is visible. Your example uses `Hidden` and not `Collapsed`. If you want to only hide the label and not collapse it you can use a converter for that.